# Share on Twitter a screen capture iOs5

Tags: iphone, twitter, ios5

I'm developing a iOs 5 app ([View in App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/social-basketball-score/id484832543?l=es&ls=1&mt=8)) with native Twitter integration recent on iOs 5.  I'm using this code for taking a screen capture of the app:

```
     if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

    // retrieve the current graphics context
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // render view into context
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];

    // create image from context
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // save image to photo album
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                   self,
                                   @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                   @"image.png"); 
 `
```

I would like that the user could automatically share on Twitter the screen capture. For sharing on Twitter I'm using that:

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *twitter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
                           [twitter setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Final score %@: %d vs. %@: %d ",intnomlocal, puntsl, intnomvisitant, puntsv]];



 //[twitter addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]];
 //[twitter addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.erwinzwart.com"]];



    [self presentViewController:twitter animated:YES completion:nil];

    twitter.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult res) {

        if(res == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone)
        {

            UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done!" message:@"Your tweet was send" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alertView show];


        }else if(res == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
        {

            UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancelled" message:@"Your tweet wasn't send" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alertView show];

        }

        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    };
```

How can I fuse those two codes. I mean, that when a button pressed, make screen capture, retain it and share it on the native Twitter above. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put them under each other, in the order they are now. In the `addImage:`-method, point to `image`, and it should work just fine. Your first code creates a `UIImage` and stores it to the users photolibrary, so you can use the `UIImage` in the twitter-code below.

Comment: I've just tried and I received gigabit error. What else... :D

Comment: But, what have I got to code:
1. [twitter addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]
2. [twitter addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:image]
Because first is string and the second is the code name

Comment: So simple: [twitter addImage:image]

Comment: As phix23 said. I suggest you read up on basic iPhone programming before continuing, as you won't get far if you don't know the difference between those :)